# No instance for (Ord int) arising from a use of `>', Haskell

Tags: haskell, compilation

other questions and problems, although similar, are not quite like this one. in this specific compiler error, the Haskell GHC won't compile the following code, for the following reason. I don't understand at all - the code is pretty straight forward.

```
--factorial

fact :: int -> int
fact 0 = 1
fact n | n > 0 = n * fact(n - 1)

main = print (fact 10)
```

(error:)

```
No instance for (Ord int) arising from a use of `>'
Possible fix:
add (Ord int) to the context of
the type signature for fact :: int -> int
In the expression: n > 0
In a stmt of a pattern guard for
an equation for `fact':
n > 0
In an equation for `fact': fact n | n > 0 = n * fact (n - 1)
```

Can you explain the problem to me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Int` is what you want:

```
fact :: int -> int
```

-->

```
fact :: Int -> Int
```

Since in Haskell, types need to begin with a cap.

Edit: Thank Yuras for commenting this:

Or if you want you could use a type class:

```
fact :: Integral a => a -> a
```

And you can name the type variable whichever you like, including `int`. Also, `Num` might fit your purpose better if you want to define factorial over general numbers.

Comment: Why not `Num int => int -> int`? :)

Comment: @Yuras Mmm, that's better - I'd prefer `Integral`, but good hint!

Comment: *facepalm* thanks. This is my first program (which contains a function) that I have ever written and compiled with Haskell.